# How to avoid massively-redundant path analysis with Neo4J/Cypher, when child-nodes have multiple parents?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This returns all unique parents exactly two generations away from "id1".

```
MATCH (:LevelOne {id: "id1"})-[:ISCHILDOF*2..2]->(parent:LevelTwo)
    RETURN DISTINCT parent ORDER BY parent.id
```

This works fine when each child has only one parent. But in my data, a node can have multiple parents (no circular relationships). According to

```
PROFILE MATCH (:LevelOne {id: "id1"})-[:ISCHILDOF*2..2]->(parent:LevelTwo)
    RETURN DISTINCT parent ORDER BY parent.id
```

With only a few thousand nodes, this result in tens of millions of path-combinations, and consistent failure due to running out of resources.

For example, given this

[image: relations]

Where "id1" is node A, and you want all its parents three generations away, you go "through" the D node twice for each child: ABDF, ACDF.

A way to avoid this redundancy is to query one generation at a time, such as starting with:

```
MATCH (:LevelOne {id: "id1"})-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
    RETURN DISTINCT parent ORDER BY parent.id
```

(The "*2..2" range is gone)

Collect the returned parents, iterate through them to gather their ids, and use them query the next generation of parents:

```
MATCH (:LevelOne {id: "id1"})-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
    WHERE child.id IN [
        'id1001',
        'id1002',
        'id1003',
        'id1004',
        'id1005',
        'id1006',
        'id1013',
        'id1014',
        'id1015',
        'id1016',
        'id1017']
    RETURN DISTINCT parent
    ORDER BY parent.id
```

Repeating this for however many generation level as required.

Is there a better, more standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated]

### Ancestors in oldest generation

This approach should work for you if you only need the ancestors in the oldest generation being searched. It is easy to generate a query for any number of generations.

Suppose you want to search for ancestors 4 generations away from the node whose `id` is "id1":

```
MATCH (:LevelOne { id: "id1" })-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
WITH DISTINCT parent AS ancestor
MATCH (ancestor)-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
WITH DISTINCT parent AS ancestor
MATCH (ancestor)-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
WITH DISTINCT parent AS ancestor
MATCH (ancestor)-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
RETURN DISTINCT parent AS ancestor;
```

The number of `MATCH` clauses corresponds to the number of generations.

[This console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=o5gefe) demonstrates this approach for 5 generations.

### Ancestors in every generation (even if not on path to oldest generation)

This approach should work for you if you want the ancestors in every generation being searched. The example below is for 4 generations.

*NOTE: This approach will list **every** ancestor in each generation, even those who are not on a path to the oldest generation.*

```
MATCH (:LevelOne { id: "id1" })-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT parent) AS ancestors
WITH [ancestors] AS generations, ancestors UNWIND ancestors AS ancestor
MATCH (ancestor)-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
WITH generations, COLLECT(DISTINCT parent) AS ancestors
WITH generations+[ancestors] AS generations, ancestors UNWIND ancestors AS ancestor
MATCH (ancestor)-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
WITH generations, COLLECT(DISTINCT parent) AS ancestors
WITH generations+[ancestors] AS generations, ancestors UNWIND ancestors AS ancestor
MATCH (ancestor)-[:ISCHILDOF]->(parent:LevelTwo)
WITH generations, COLLECT(DISTINCT parent) AS ancestors
RETURN generations+[ancestors] AS generations;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you show how to return ancestors in multiple generations? I've postfixed each generations' parent and ancestor with a number (`parent1 AS ancestor1`), but I'm unclear how to return more than just the deepest ancestor generation (`RETURN DISTINCT parent5 as ancestor5`). Something like--although I know this syntax is wrong--`RETURN DISTINCT ancestor2, ancestor3, ancestor4`.

Comment: That is a lot more complex -- especially if you only want the ancestors that are along a path to an ancestor in the oldest generation. It is a bit easier (but still complex) to see *all* ancestors at each generation

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to see all ancestors in each generation.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I think my choice would be to use the first query, one generation at a time.